# Add title when hovering on emoticons in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this sample code for replacing text with emoticons when message is submitted. However, I want to add title on emoticons when mouse hover to it to identify what kind of emoticon user used, how can I achieved that in my current code? thanks

```
<html>
 <head>
   <title>Testing Emoticon</title>
 </head>
 <body>
   <input type="text" name="message" id="message">
   <br><br>
 <div class="results"></div>
 <script language="javascript" src="./assets/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
 <script>
   function replaceEmoticons(text) {
     var emoticons = {
       ':-)' : 'smile.png',
       ':)'  : 'smile.png',
       ';)'  : 'wink.png',
       ';-)' : 'wink.png',
       ':P'  : 'tongue.png'
     }, url = "http://localhost/cb/2/assets/img/smileys/", patterns = [],
     metachars = /[[\]{}()*+?.\\|^$\-,&#\s]/g;

     // build a regex pattern for each defined property
     for (var i in emoticons) {
       if (emoticons.hasOwnProperty(i)){ // escape metacharacters
         patterns.push('('+i.replace(metachars, "\\$&")+')');
       }
     }

     // build the regular expression and replace
     return text.replace(new RegExp(patterns.join('|'),'g'), function(match) {
       return typeof emoticons[match] != 'undefined' ?
           '<img src="'+url+emoticons[match]+'"/>' :
           match;
     });
   }
 </script>
 <script>
   $('#message').keypress(function(e){
     if(e.which == 13){//Enter key pressed
       e.preventDefault();
       var emoticon = $('#message').val();
       $('.results').html(replaceEmoticons(emoticon));
     }
   });
 </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Main purpose is solved, when you type `:)` the output title on hover is `smile` that came from `smile.png` thanks to @PraveenKumar

Additional question is can I customize the title, like if I type `:P` the output of title might be `Stick Out Tongue` instead of `tongue` that came from `tongue.png` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add it while replacing:

```
return text.replace(new RegExp(patterns.join('|'),'g'), function(match) {
  return typeof emoticons[match] != 'undefined' ?
    '<img src="'+url+emoticons[match]+'" title="' + emoticons[match].substr(0, emoticons[match].length-4) + '" />' :
  match;
});
```

**Working Bin: http://jsbin.com/cotefuwate/edit?output**

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, but this is the output I want to achieved, when I type `:)` the title must be `Smile` and not `:)` thanks

Comment: I think the substring part must be change because the output becomes `.png`

Comment: the period is gone and the output now is `png`

Comment: @LeViNcE Give me some time. I guess I am drowsy. LoL.

Comment: @LeViNcE Man, 100 £, if this doesn't work: http://jsbin.com/cotefuwate/edit?html,output

Comment: Nice one @Praveen Kumar thank you very much for the time (happy)
One last question if you mind, Can I customize the title, like if I type `:lol:` the output of title might be `Laughing Out Loud` instead of `lol` ? thanks again

Comment: Well, you might need to add extra info with your definition. @LeViNcE... Possible, if you use an array in your JSON.

Comment: Here's my updated definition: [Current functions](http://jsbin.com/vuvodijade/edit?html,output)
It consumes 2 functions I want it to integrate to only one function to avoid heavy functions

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, we have different timezones, here its only 10:08am, No problem @Praveen Kumar you can take a rest, this function is not urgent, thanks again for your help :)

Comment: @LeViNcE You could have left my answer accepted, and I can vote up your answer if you wish... `:)`

Comment: ah ok I'm sorry, I'm newbie here at stackoverflow, ok sorry for my mistake,  thank you I will revert back my accepted answer

Comment: @LeViNcE Added a vote to you! `:)` Enjoy your `10` pts... :D

Answer (score 1):

For my additional question, I came up with a solution base on my research and trial error tests.

I've got an idea when I see this link [javascript emotify](http://benalman.com/code/projects/javascript-emotify/examples/emotify/) by Ben Alman.

So I reconstruct my codes and came up to this:

I modified my json array to add more data.

```
var emoticons = {
  ':-)' : ['smile.png', 'Smile'],
  ':)'  : ['smile.png', 'Smile'],
  ';)'  : ['wink.png', 'Wink'],
  ';-)' : ['wink.png', 'Wink'],
  ':P'  : ['tongue.png', 'Stick Out Tongue']
}, url = "http://localhost/cb/2/assets/img/smileys/", patterns = [],
     metachars = /[[\]{}()*+?.\\|^$\-,&#\s]/g;
```

And also this part of the function to match my new json array:

```
// build the regular expression and replace
return text.replace(new RegExp(patterns.join('|'),'g'), function (match) {
  return typeof emoticons[match][0] != 'undefined' ?
      '<img src="'+url+emoticons[match][0]+'" title="' + emoticons[match][1] + '" />' :
      match;
});
```

Now its really working according to my needs. Hooray!